# How to search multiple locators using a single find in ruby capybara?

Tags: ruby, xpath, capybara

In Ruby/Capybara, I tried searching multiple(two) locators(css) in a single find query and found that it automatically search both of them and perform the action on the locator which is present on page.
Ex-
`find("css1","css2").set "ABC"`

I observed that while running the script, at run time it search for both the locators and will perform the action on the one which is present on page.

However, When I tried the same logic using xpath, it dont work and throw element not found error or invalid selector(one xpath is present on page).
ex-
`find(:xpath,"xpath1","xpath2").set "ABC"`

Can anyone please help how we can do it for xpath also in ruby capybara.

Comment: How about using XPath union operator : `find(:xpath,"xpath1|xpath2").set "ABC"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you show of `find("css1","css2").set "ABC"` won't actually do anything with the "css2" argument passed and, in the current version of Capybara, will actually emit a warning about unused parameters.  What will work would be

```
find("css1, css2").set("ABC")
```

because it's using the grouping comma which will find items matching either css1 or css2.  In XPath you can do that with the union operator | which will return elements that match xpath1 or xpath2

```
find(:xpath, "xpath1 | xpath2").set("ABC")
```